# Why does Text disappear when i click submit?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

When I type in my EditText view to fill out all the required information and then click submit. Everything I typed disappears. I want this text to remain. I am guessing there is something wrong with my `@State` objects but cannot figure out what.

SignUpViewModel

```
class SignUpViewModel : ObservableObject {

    @Published
    var error: String? = nil

    @Published
    var goHome: Bool = false

    @Published
    var goToLogin: Bool = false

    func onGoToLoginClicked() {
        self.goToLogin = true
    }

    func signUp(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, birthday: String, phoneNumber: String, password: String, confirmPassword: String) {
        if (firstName.count < 3) {
            error = "Please enter first name"
            return
        }
        if (lastName.count < 3) {
            error = "Please enter last name"
            return
        }
        if (!email.isEmail()) {
            error = "Pleaes enter valid email"
            return
        }
        if (birthday.isEmpty) {
            error = "Pleae enter valid birthday"
            return
        }
        if (!phoneNumber.isDigits) {
            error = "Please enter valid phone number"
            return
        }
        if (password.count < 8) {
            error = "Please enter a password that is at least 8 characters long"
        }
        if (password != confirmPassword) {
            error = "Password do not match"
        }
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { authResult, error in
            if authResult != nil {
                self.goHome = true
            } else {
                self.error = error?.localizedDescription
            }
        })
    }
}
```

SignUp View

```
struct SignUpScreen: View {

    @State
    var firstName: String = ""
    @State
    var lastName: String = ""
    @State
    var birthday: String = ""
    @State
    var number: String = ""
    @State
    var email: String = ""
    @State
    var password: String = ""
    @State
    var confirmPassword: String = ""

    @EnvironmentObject
    var viewModel: SignUpViewModel


    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                VClearBackground()
                Spacer()
            }
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Group {
                        PreHeaderText(header: "Get Started")
                            .alignmentGuide(.leading, computeValue: { d in
                                d[.leading]
                            })
                            .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 32, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        HeaderText(header: "Create Account")
                        EditText(hint: "Huey", text: $firstName, label: "FIRST NAME", textContentType: UITextContentType.name)
                        EditText(hint: "Freeman", text: $lastName, label: "LAST NAME", textContentType: UITextContentType.name)
                        EditText(hint: "04-19-1994", text: $birthday, label: "BIRTHDAY")
                        EditText(hint: "(281) 456-7890)", text: $number, label: "MOBILE NUMBER", textContentType: UITextContentType.telephoneNumber, keyboardType: UIKeyboardType.phonePad)
                        EditText(hint: "email@exmaple.com", text: $email, label: "EMAIL", textContentType: UITextContentType.emailAddress)
                        EditText(hint: "********", text: $password, label: "PASSWORD", textContentType: UITextContentType.newPassword)
                        EditText(hint: "********", text: $confirmPassword, label: "CONFIRM PASSWORD", textContentType: UITextContentType.newPassword)
                    }
                    Group {
                        if self.viewModel.error != nil {
                            HStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Text(viewModel.error ?? "")
                                    .foregroundColor(ColorTheme.error.color)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            .padding()
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            VowerButton(text: "Submit") {
                                self.viewModel.signUp(firstName: self.firstName, lastName: self.lastName, email: self.email, birthday: self.birthday, phoneNumber: self.number, password: self.password, confirmPassword: self.confirmPassword)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding()

                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            NavigationLink(destination: LoginScreen(), isActive: $viewModel.goToLogin) {
                                CtaText(text: "Have an account?", cta: "Login") {
                                    self.viewModel.onGoToLoginClicked()
                                }
                            }
                            .padding()
                            Spacer()
                        }

                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 16, leading: 16, bottom: 16, trailing: 16))
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        }
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.black, ColorTheme.brandPurple.color]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

EditText View

```
struct EditText: View {

    var hint: String
    @Binding
    var text: String
    var label: String = ""
    var defaultValue =  ""
    var textContentType: UITextContentType? = .none
    var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType = .default

    private func initializeDefaultValue() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.text = self.defaultValue
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        initializeDefaultValue()
        return VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(label).font(.system(size: 12)).bold()
                .foregroundColor(ColorTheme.text.color)
            HStack {
                TextField(hint, text: $text)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .textContentType(textContentType)
                .keyboardType(keyboardType)
                    .foregroundColor(ColorTheme.text.color)
            }
            Divider().background(Color(ColorTheme.brandBlue.value))
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 12, leading: 0, bottom: 8, trailing: 0))
    }
}
```

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `EditText` view.

```swift
struct EditText: View {

    var hint: String
    @Binding
    var text: String
    var label: String = ""
    var defaultValue =  ""
    var textContentType: UITextContentType? = .none
    var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType = .default

    private func initializeDefaultValue() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.text = self.defaultValue
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        initializeDefaultValue()
        return VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(label).font(.system(size: 12)).bold()
                .foregroundColor(ColorTheme.text.color)
            HStack {
                TextField(hint, text: $text)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .textContentType(textContentType)
                .keyboardType(keyboardType)
                    .foregroundColor(ColorTheme.text.color)
            }
            Divider().background(Color(ColorTheme.brandBlue.value))
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 12, leading: 0, bottom: 8, trailing: 0))
    }
}
```

Specifically, it's in the `body` property. This is a computed property that is fetched by SwiftUI whenever the view is recomputed. In this case, this happens when the `error` property of the `SignUpScreen` view changes, as all the subviews are recomputed.

When this `EditText` view is recomputed, the `initializeDefaultValue()` function is called (it's the first line in the `body` property). This clears the text fields.

As for a solution, I'm not sure why you actually need the `initializeDefaultValue` function in here at all. It seems best suited for the ViewModel or some other location.

---

Also, just some other things that I saw:

```
func signUp(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, birthday: String, phoneNumber: String, password: String, confirmPassword: String) {
    if (firstName.count < 3) {
        error = "Please enter first name"
        return
    }
    if (lastName.count < 3) {
        error = "Please enter last name"
        return
    }
    if (!email.isEmail()) {
        error = "Pleaes enter valid email"
        return
    }
    if (birthday.isEmpty) {
        error = "Pleae enter valid birthday"
        return
    }
    if (!phoneNumber.isDigits) {
        error = "Please enter valid phone number"
        return
    }
    if (password.count < 8) {
        error = "Please enter a password that is at least 8 characters long"
    }
    if (password != confirmPassword) {
        error = "Password do not match"
    }
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { authResult, error in
        if authResult != nil {
            self.goHome = true
        } else {
            self.error = error?.localizedDescription
        }
    })
}
```

This function returns early in all error cases except the last two — I believe this was a mistake.

```swift
if self.viewModel.error != nil {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        Text(viewModel.error ?? "")
        .foregroundColor(ColorTheme.error.color)
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
}
```

This part of the `SignUpScreen` view should be able to be simplified to this:

```swift
if let err = self.viewModel.error {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        Text(err)
        .foregroundColor(ColorTheme.error.color)
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
}
```

or, if if-let statements are not allowed in this case:

```swift
if self.viewModel.error != nil {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        Text(viewModel.error!)
        .foregroundColor(ColorTheme.error.color)
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
}
```

as you know that the error is non-`nil`.

---

Hope all of this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem code is in `SignUpScreen`:

```
@ObservedObject
var viewModel: SignUpViewModel = SignUpViewModel()
```

Whenever the view is re-evaluated, a new `SignUpViewModel` is created.

You can create the view model outside the view, and either pass it to the directly to the constructor, or inject it to the environment using `environmentObject()`.

To use an environment object instead, change the above declaration to:

```
@EnvironmentObject
var viewModel: SignUpViewModel
```

And then create your view like this:

```
var signUpViewModel = SignUpViewModel()

// ...

SignUpScreen()
    .environmentObject(signUpViewModel)
```

Comment: A code sample showing environmentobject is generally appreciated

Comment: Added in the answer above.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested but the problem still persists. I then tried making the `@State` variables `@Published` and putting them in the ViewModel. However then every time I try to type a character, it deletes it.

Comment: Remove the call to `initializeDefaultValue()` - it changes the text to "" each time the view is state is changed.